# Ember.js: native input type="number" binding broke when constraining value

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Using the new one-way binding of native inputs, I'm trying to stop the data at "999". It appears to constrain it once and reset it back to "999", but then the binding is lost and it continues unbounded.

```
<input type="number" value={{count}} oninput={{action "update" value="target.value"}} />
```

js:

```
actions: {
  update(value) {
    if (value > 999) {
      this.set('count', 999);
    } else { 
      this.set('count', value);
    }
  }
}
```

twiddle that demonstrates issue: https://ember-twiddle.com/e4801208572aec5b0548553293a83afd

Am I doing something wrong?

linking github issue: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/13747

Answer (score 0):

It is because your bind value={{count}} in template.

If the action update value, count will be affected on template as well.

With that say, for everything less than 999, count will be as same as input, but your action which trigged by keyUp will change the count which affect value as well.

I would say it is not one-way binding.